# Vermont Casting Propane Fireplace

Tags: heating

I have a Vermont Castings Stardance millivolt unit. I recently had my thermo coupler replaced and pilot light was back. Due to this being in a  rental, I never really noticed until now (about a month later after TC replacement) but the unit is controlled by a mechanical thermostat and when it’s kicks on, it shuts off after 20-30 minutes without getting to set temperature. Seems to be the same amount of time every time….any thoughts on this?

Comment: More details please. Have you been using a master on/off switch to control the fireplace or have you been using the thermostat? Where is the thermostat in relation to the fireplace? When it turns itself off after 20-30 minutes, does it ever come back on by itself or do you have to do something (what?) to make it come on again? What happens if you set the thermostat to the highest possible temperature? Depending on details, this may be either an incorrect anticipator setting or bad calibration, but we need your answers to the above to narrow down the cause.

Comment: I have been using a thermostat to control this unit. The thermostat is approximately 20 feet a way on a way…been in that location for past 5 years. I set the anticipator to recommended setting of 1.2 but had the same result from fireplace with two separate thermostats. These are the LUX basic ones but all of my previous ones had the same anticipator setting. When I set the temp on the thermostat to highest setting it will go on and then off after 30 minutes and really only way I get it to go back on is turn thermostat back to 50 (which it ironically clicks) and then back up to get it on again.

Comment: What is the model number of the Lux thermostat?

Comment: AT10-1141SA…could it be as simple as the pilot light being directly or flame on thermocoupler not positioned correctly with flame?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My problem is the fireplace use to run for however long it took to get to desired temperature; now it shuts off after 30 minutes…

Answer (score 1):

I've had a look at your thermostat's installation instructions and I don't see how the thermostat could be involved in the issue. I'm not sure exactly what the problem is, but here is a way to eliminate the thermostat as the source of the problem so at least you can stop replacing thermostats.

There should be two wires from the fireplace attached to the thermostat. Make note of where / how they attach to the thermostat, disconnect them from the thermostat and wire-nut them together. The fireplace should light.

Remain in the vicinity and see if the fireplace continues running for longer than the usual 20-30 minutes.

**If the fireplace turns off by itself**, immediately separate the thermostat wires, then re-connect them. If the fireplace lights again, the thermostat is not involved. I suggest that you post a new question about the fireplace problem and supply the model number of the fireplace.

**If the fireplace continues running indefinitely**, the problem is with the thermostat. Review the installation instructions to see if you followed them, and if you did, contact Lux customer service. The thermostat has a 3-year warranty.